# Sklearn: OneHotEncoder, CategoricalEncoder & OrdinalEncoder not working

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm working through Hands on ML with Sklearn & TF... I cannot get ANY of the categorical encoding functions to import/work properly.
I've updated to latest version, and re-installed various versions, the closest I've gotten is:
 OneHotEncoder actually importing, however it still won't encode the categorical data with this code:

```
housing_cat = housing[['ocean_proximity']]
housing_cat.head(10)

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

cat_encoder = OneHotEncoder()
housing_cat_encoded = cat_encoder.fit_transform(housing_cat)
housing_cat_encoded

housing_cat_encoded.head(10)
```

I get this error message:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'NEAR BAY'

Please advise. This library is driving me crazy with these dumb updates and name changes.

Comment: Cannot replicate, different Dataset though, if your dataset is publicly available share link, else checkout https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ORUr6HONW-7dP0QxkvR8ynCFXBXJlxhe

Comment: use {get_dummies} from pandas
{new_housing = pd.get_dummies(housing)}

Comment: Which version of scikit-learn are you using?